# Identify this capacitor marked 'ū1 22c RA'

Tags: capacitor, identification

Can anyone tell me the specs of this capacitor?

Specsheet says `22MF 20% 16V`, but I'm not sure what capacity exactly the `M` stands for. And it has `C` or Ohm on the capacitor itself. It is confusing.

[image]

Comment: 22 Mega-Farads? Wow~ That pic must be taken from way up in the air!! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That capacitor matches the definition, at least according to some manufacturer's capacitor markings.

For markings according to Nichicon the top row is lot number, middle row is capacitance and voltage code, and bottom row is capacitor series.

I did not find Nichicon series RA but otherwise the markings are consistent. 22 meaning capacitance in microfarads (uF) and C is voltage code for 16V.

And 20% is quite typical for electrolytic capacitors, it can be assumed by default, but as there is little room for printing anything extra, it's just the capacitor series that has some tolerance so there is no need to separately print it.

Answer (score 0):

Here, "MF" means "microfarad".  This is a capacitor, so it's in (micro)farads, not Ohms (measure of resistance).